# Minimum annihilating polynomial of matrix $A$ of order $n$ is equal to $(λ + 1)^2(λ - 2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial

Minimum annihilating polynomial of matrix $A$ of order $n$ is equal to $(λ + 1)^2(λ - 2)$. What can be said about the minimal annihilating polynomial of matrix $A^2$? Justify the answer.

While working on a solution, I noticed that the eigenvalues must be squared, so we get $(t−1)^2(t−4)$. Nevertheless, I'm not certain about my findings and where to go next.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, multiplied Jordan matrix as a block matrix and noticed, that cells cannot become larger in size, as well as fewer (cell size does not change). But the eigenvalues ​​are squared. So, annihilating polynomial is equal to $(t-1)^2(t-4)$. On the other hand, multiplying one matrix transformation by another, we transform over the spaces. Hence, we have $A*A$ which means, that the eigenvalues must be squared, so we get $(t-1)^2(t-4)$. Still, I'm not quite sure that my thoughts goes in right direction.

Comment: That the eigenvalues are squared is a good start. If you add this to your question, it has the context that is expected here.